# Another site not owned by us chosen for the Google-selected canonical

Tags: google-search-console, canonical-url

One of our sites is affected by negative SEO. In our Google Search Console, we notice that Google has chosen a different domain as the canonical URL.  We don't own that domain.   How it got there is UNKNOWN.

[image: WRONG Canonical URL FOR https://techcrub.com]

How do we fix this?

Comment: You seem to be indexed fine with the https version of your page. I would verify your https site with Google Search Console and check the page there.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath the second site is not ours, did you see that?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant is that you are looking at http://techrub.com/ when you should be looking at https://techrub.com/ the s in https is important and means you are looking at the wrong property.

Comment: Same result even with the HTTPS

Comment: Your home pages content seems to all be generated with JavaScript. I wonder if Google is unable to see that content and therefore struggling to find it as a unique page. Try a live test to see if Google does execute your code and adds the content to the page. I did a mobile friendly test on it and it looks like the code may not be running.

Comment: I use WordPress and the popular NEWSPAPER theme i have been using since 4YRS now so i don't know what changed.