# Google does not index pages and defines wrong canonical

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, canonical-url, jekyll

## Contex

I have a domain, [andrasnovoszath.com](https://andrasnovoszath.com) which previously I redirected to another one [bcdataanalytics.com](https://bcdataanalytics.com). About a month ago I stopped the redirect and started to write posts on it as on a separate site.

## Issue

Google does not index the pages, save a few early ones, and only one later one. Even more, in the search results, it shows a page from [bcdataanalytics.com](https://bcdataanalytics.com), that is, from the page to where I redirected this page previously.

I checked and the google search console seems to believe that the canonical page is the one I was redirecting to (even though there is no overlapping content at all):

> User-declared canonical: https://andrasnovoszath.com/andrasnovoszath.com/
>
> Google-selected canonical: https://www.bcdataanalytics.com/

I requested reindex multiple times but that did not help.

## Similar issues

I reviewed this StackExchange for similar issues but most of the canonical problems were about actual duplicate content or slight variations of the same URL (e.g. translations). The closest thing I found was [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/126668/another-site-not-owned-by-us-chosen-for-the-google-selected-canonical) but there is no solution.

## Further info

- I also raised the issue at [support.google.com/webmasters](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/74915234?hl=en) but I did not receive any response yet.
- As this is a static webpage generated with fastpages, I try to generate a sitemap, but so far with [little success](https://forums.fast.ai/t/fastpages-sitemap-and-or-upgrade/79897).

I would appreciate any tips, ideas on how to approach the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You probably just need to wait.  It can take Google a few months to get everything straight after you change your redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well, then, I just wait. Is there perhaps a way to speed up Google a bit? I am thinking about generating some links but I am not sure if that helps or if there is anything more sensible out there.